# How to parse text without nested html elements using Jericho?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jericho-html-parser

Using Jericho, I need to parse something like this:

```
<html>
<div class="title">
    Spoon bows
    <br/>
    <span>
        A Matrix scene.
        <br/>
        Matrix 1
    </span>
</div>
</html>
```

I want to parse "Spoon bows", but I get the whole content within the `<div>` tag using the following code:

```
List<Element> list = item.getAllElementsByClass("title");
if(list!=null) {
    Element title = list.get(0);
    if(title!=null) {
        String text = title.getContent().getTextExtractor().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the unformatted code snippet, I somehow can't get it right, though I use 4 spaces and such...

Comment: The text editor has a "code" formatter. It will automatically indent your code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you:

```
private String getTextContent(Element elem) {
    String text = elem.getContent().toString();

    final List<Element> children = elem.getChildElements();
    for (Element child : children) {
        text = text.replace(child.toString(), "");
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: This will break for some cases, e.g. <a>A text<b>A text</b></a>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could iterate over children elements of your title node.

Take a look at this question: [How to iterate over plain text segments with the Jericho HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621252/how-to-iterate-over-plain-text-segments-with-the-jericho-html-parser)